# How to fill lists in exception block with a string or numeric value when the element is not found?

Tags: python, selenium, try-except

I am iterating through some web scraped data and I am trying to put the results into one of two list. There is a case where the split used below raises exception to skip the record because there essentially is no ' at ' in the entry. If I run the code for 10 records and this was the situation for one of those records then I would have 10 in a_list and 9 in b_list. I want to keep everything matched up correctly and keep 10 records in both list but put in a blank or some string like "null" or 0 into the list where the exception was true. After this, I want the script to continue doing its thing. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

```
a_list = [];    b_list = [];

for i in range(1,11):
    try:
        a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('abc').text.split(' at ')[0]
        b = driver.find_element_by_xpath('abc').text.split(' at ')[1]
        a_list.append(a)
        b_list.append(b)
    except: 
        continue
    i +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append within the `except` block.

```
a_list = [];    b_list = [];

for i in range(1,11):
    try:
        a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('abc').text.split(' at ')[0]
        b = driver.find_element_by_xpath('abc').text.split(' at ')[1]
        a_list.append(a)
        b_list.append(b)
    except: 
        a_list.append(None)
        b_list.append(None)
```

Also you do not need to increment the loop variable. `for` loop does that for you

Comment: This did the trick. I don't know why I didn't think of trying that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    try:
        element_splitted = driver.find_element_by_xpath('abc').text.split(' at ')
    except:   # No element found
        a_list.append(None)
        b_list.append(None)
        continue

    if len(element_splitted) > 1:  # it has ' at '
        a_list.append(element_splitted[0])
        b_list.append(element_splitted[1])
    else:
        a_list.append(None)
        b_list.append(None)
```

I haven't used Selenium before but I guess this is how it works. First I checked it the element was found. Then I checked if it has `" at "` in it.

Additional notes:

No need to increment `i`.

Do not use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('abc').text.split(' at ')` part twice.

Do not use broad exception handler like me --> check the document for specific exception that would raise.